# Unable to copy and modify attribute in XSLT when using a namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to transform an XML document and modify the attributes of single element but the transform is not getting applied if the root element has a namespace attribute. Simply removing xmlns works fine with my code.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BIDomain xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/biee/bi-domain">
  <BIInstance name="coreapplication">
    <SecurityOptions sslManualConfig="false" sslEnabled="false" ssoProvider="Custom" ssoEnabled="false">
      <SecurityService>
        <EndpointURI>bisecurity/service</EndpointURI>
      </SecurityService>
    </SecurityOptions>
  </BIInstance>
</BIDomain>
```

The XSL used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" standalone="yes" />

  <!-- Copying everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Add the new attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="SecurityOptions">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="ssoProviderLogoffURL"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="ssoProviderLogonURL"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="sslVerifyPeers">
                <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
            </xsl:attribute>           
            <xsl:apply-templates  select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The end result is the same XML. If I remove the namespace definition from the root element
    `<BIDomain xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/biee/bi-domain">` the transform gets applied normally. I'm assuming that I'm doing something wrong and the namespace attribute is interfering with the matching.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element you're trying to match is in a namespace (the default namespace), so you need to properly use namespaces in your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:bi="http://www.oracle.com/biee/bi-domain">
                  <!--   ^----- here   -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" standalone="yes" />

  <!-- Copying everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Add the new attributes -->
                <!--   v------- and here   -->
  <xsl:template match="bi:SecurityOptions">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="ssoProviderLogoffURL"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="ssoProviderLogonURL"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="sslVerifyPeers">
        <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
      </xsl:attribute>           
      <xsl:apply-templates  select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  I'd just add for clarity: it's easy to assume that the default namespace means you don't need to namespace qualify the element in the XSLT - but you do.  You could achieve this by making `http://www.oracle.com/biee/bi-domain` the default xmlns for the XSLT, but that would be pretty confusing down the line...

Comment: @DanField Using a default namespace in the XSLT would not eliminate the need to declare and use a prefix for it in `match=""`, and `select=""` attributes. XPath 1.0 does not allow for non-null default namespaces.

Comment: The spec might not allow it, but various implementations do..  see http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwH for example.  Regardless it'd be really bad practice.  I'm more saying it to highlight the idea (that when you don't prefix it, it's assuming it's in the default namespace)

Comment: @DanField Yes, I realize what your main point was. That processor you linked to is working correctly - the `SecurityOptions` template is simply going unused. You can see this because there is no `ssoProviderLogoffURL` attribute in the result.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I ignored that part. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

xmlns works such that all nodes inherit the xmlns attribute(s) from their parent. What that means is, unless otherwise specified, when your document root contains
`xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/biee/bi-domain"`
it applies that namespace to all of the sub tree.

So you're actually looking for a `SecurityOptions` tag with a namespace of `"http://www.oracle.com/biee/bi-domain"`.

This means that your XSLT will actually need to have something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tmp="http://www.oracle.com/biee/bi-domain">
```

at the top and the template match would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="tmp:SecurityOptions">
```

Note the tmp: matches the xmlns:tmp; this is called a namespace prefix and allows xml to match the small string of `tmp` to the large string of `"http://www.oracle.com/biee/bi-domain"`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. However I marked the previous answer since he posted it faster.